# Crystal Report in Production Server

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I need to deploy an ASP.NET application with Crystal Report to a Production Server, should I install the Redistributable or purchase the full version?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need the runtime, but the version will depend on which version you developed your application with.

[Crystal runtime for visual studio 2010](http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Deploying+Crystal+Reports+for+Visual+Studio+2010+Runtime) on the production server for 13. Pay particular attention to the deployment section of the wiki.

For the older version, [crystal reports runtime for visual studio 2008](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-27942)